# How can I have a horizontal set of checkboxes in plone ploneformgen?

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I wish to select different values for the seven days of a week eg:

```
Category: A  Equipment: XYZ  
Status    Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday Saturday   
Good        X        X                  X         X        X  
Bad                           X

Category: A  Equipment: BCD
Status    Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday Saturday   
Fine                X        X          X         X       X
Defective   X
```

I have used datagrid at the moment to achieve this. I would like to know if there is a still better way to achieve this? Coz for each category there are several equipments and for each equipment I will have to create the grid and copy/paste the days and create the different status(which differ for each equipment) fields to select for each equipment. I don't want to use the rating-scale field for the days(in rows) and status (in columns) as the form would not look good and become very long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do each set of check boxes as a muti-select field, rendered as check boxes. Then, just use CSS to make each label/checkbox combination into a block, all float left.

Details: http://developer.plone.org/forms/ploneformgen/restyle.html#putting-checkboxes-in-a-row